# Why AWS IoT allows us to communicate with a "thing" without a certificate

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, certificate, x509certificate, iot

AWS IoT states that communication between a device and AWS IoT is protected through the use of X.509 certificates.

Why is it that I can simply create a "thing" (via the Amazon CLI or SDK for example) and update its shadow etc. without attaching a certificate for security?

How to configure AWS IoT to only allow things / devices to be available with certificates?